# Jenkins Pipeline plugin MissingPropertyException No such property: node for class: groovy.lang.Binding

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have several pipeline jobs configured in jenkins and all of them were working properly. Suddenly, they all stopped working with the following error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: node for class: groovy.lang.Binding
at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:130)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:155)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:159)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:1)
at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureBlock.eval(ClosureBlock.java:46)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$101(SandboxContinuable.java:34)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.lambda$run0$0(SandboxContinuable.java:59)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:58)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:174)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:332)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:83)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:244)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:232)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Jenkins version is 2.121.3
The pipeline plugin is 2.4
The pipeline utility steps plugin is 2.0.2

The job is very  basic, but any job will fail with the same error. If I remove the "node" line, the job will fail on stage, or basically any instruction in the script.

```
 node {
   stage('Clean up Workspace') {
    deleteDir()
   }
   stage('Set environment file') {       
   }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We faced the same problem. A downgrade of the Script Security plugin fixed the problem.

Comment: Thank you, such a life-saver! Here is the related issue in Jenkins issue tracker https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-53420

Comment: Thank you for the answer, much appreciated. I had a back up of the previous configuration so I just replaced all the plugins with the previous version and issue is gone. It is good to know the exact plugin causing the issue.

Comment: Note that they've fixed this bug in script-security 1.46, so it's ok to upgrade (just don't apply 1.45) ;)

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue, with a fresh Jenkins install.
Manually downgraded `script-securit` plugin via from https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/script-security/ fixed this.

Browsing to `JENKINS_URL:PORT/pluginManager/advanced`, uploading `hpi` file and restarting.